# Singleton class DataLoader - set values from Core Data in AppDelegate, however cannot access DataLoader variables in other classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, core-data, singleton

I have been wracking my brain, and a lot of searching, but no luck so far.

Basically, I have setup Core Data to load data from an sqlite db in my AppDelegate class into shared variables in a singleton class called DataLoader.

I also have a main class called GameScene, which will also use DataLoader data.

What I am trying to do is as follows:

- load data from DB (using the background thread) and store results in DataLoader singleton class variables (specifically an NSMutableArray)
- In this way the data is loaded while the scenes transition to main menu area
- In the GameScene class I try to access the data stored in the DataLoader singleton, and use this data in the game.

My issue is that although I can see that I store objects in the AppDelegate class, I don't seem able to return the objects in the GameScene class. Usually ends in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I am really looking for some example of something similar or if you have any ideas.

If you need code samples, let me know.

Thanks,
Pras.

****EDIT - Code Snippets****

DataLoader.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface DataLoader : NSObject {

}

//setup singleton
+(DataLoader *) sharedDataLoader;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * veHint;//2 characters
```

DataLoader.m

```
#import "DataLoader.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@implementation DataLoader
@synthesize veHint;

static DataLoader * myDataLoader = nil;

+(DataLoader *) sharedDataLoader{

    if(myDataLoader == nil){
        myDataLoader = [[[DataLoader alloc]init]retain];
    }
    return myDataLoader;
}

-(id) init
{
    if((self = [super init])){
        veHint = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    }
    return self;
}
```

AppDelegate.mm

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GameScene.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Word.h"
#import "DataLoader.h"
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
//other standard stuff here...

//my load data method using data loader
[self getRandomData];

//other standard stuff here...

// Run the intro Scene
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [GameScene node]];
}

//other standard methods for Core Data

//Random data loader

-(void) fetchRandomData: (NSString *) searchInteger{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"fetching random data for word size: %@", searchInteger);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Word" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    //setup predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == %@", @"size", searchInteger];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil; 
    NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
    NSLog(@"fetch results count = %i", [fetchResults count]);
    [request release];

    NSMutableArray * results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    NSMutableArray * fetchedIndexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    //get the total count, randomize selection of 10 results from the list

    int j = 0;
    while (j<10) {
        int index = arc4random() % [fetchResults count];
        //get only unique values
        if ([fetchedIndexes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]] == false)     {
            [fetchedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];

            Word * word = (Word *) [fetchResults objectAtIndex:index];
            //NSLog(@"j = %i, index = %i, wordsize = %@, wordstring = %@",j, index, word.size, word.wordString);
            [results addObject:word];
            j++;

        }
    }
    //set dataloader 
    [[DataLoader sharedDataLoader] setVeHint:results];

    [pool drain];   

}
```

Also, need to mention that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is on the [pool drain] call in AppDelegate.mm.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, sample code will clarify your issue and make it easier to find the problems.

Comment: so many thing can go wrong in life... I don't know which one to pick... ;-( How are you trying to acces data in your singleton, and how your singleton is define. Are you thread safe with that singleton? those info should help us help you.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for quick reply. The code is very similar to Ray Wenderlich's Core Data tutorial ([http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started][1]) for Core Data. I have an sqlite db, which is loaded in. I then have a method getRandomData(), which contains the NSFetchRequest. In this method, the results I fetch are filtered and this is where I set the Data Loader NSMutableArray variable.
There is very little deviation from this Core Data methods, so I am not sure if that answers your questions?

  [1]: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Code snippets added - sorry for delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably somewhere in the code (I think it is memory/scope-related, like too early release etc.). It really shouldn't matter how you access your data as long as you're keeping every piece of it properly "memory managed".

I can show you how I do this kind of data management.

I usually name it `DataManager`:

**DataManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataManager : NSObject {
    NSDate *someDate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *someDate;

+(DataManager*)sharedInstance;
- (void)loadSettings;
- (void)saveSettings;

@end
```

**DataManager.m**

```
#import "DataManager.h"

static DataManager *dataManagerInstance;

@implementation DataManager

@synthesize someDate = _someDate;

// singleton method
+(DataManager*)sharedInstance {
    if(!dataManagerInstance) {
        dataManagerInstance = [[DataManager alloc] init];
    }
    return dataManagerInstance;
}

- (void)saveSettings {
    // save your data   
}

- (void)loadSettings {
    // load your data
}
```

I hope you got the idea… maybe you post some code snippets so we can find what's going wrong with your singleton ;-)

Update: OK, so you added code snippets and the problem is obviously in this line:

```
[[DataLoader sharedDataLoader] setVeHint:results];
```

You are setting veHint to be `results`, so you are overwriting your private variable of DataLoader. You shouldn't do it that way, since `results` is released and DataLoader gets lost of the reference.

You should either write another setter method, which makes a copy of `results` and puts the elements in `veHint`

or

retain `results` after passing it to DataLoader like this:

```
[[DataLoader sharedDataLoader] setVeHint:[results retain]];
```

However, this solution (and also yours) creates a memory leak, since you retained `veHint` in `DataLoader` and overwrite it in your Delegate (you completely lose the reference to `veHint`).

Comment: In terms of the singleton, the sample given by septi above is pretty much the code I have for the singleton DataLoader class, except I have variables of NSMutableArray and a method to return a specific value within an NSMutableArray.

Comment: I think the problem is **how you return** and manage the objects you're passing around. You really should upload some code ;-)

Comment: Code snippets added as requests - sorry for delay.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is not thread safe by default. If you are trying to use it on multiple threads, make sure you are familiar with [Apple's guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1).

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind that Core Data is not a singleton. In fact I just have the bog standard methods to access an sqlite DB from the App Delegate class. I just want to use the result fetch from the DB and set the variable within the singleton class, so that my main game scene can access the filtered data. If that makes sense.